# Running a shell script in PHP which insert the output data into a MYSQL database?

Tags: php, mysql, linux

I am trying to run a script shell from a PHP inline code, its output should be inserted into a MYSQL table. How can that be done?

Comment: Have you already tried anything or written any code yourself? Stack Overflow is for helping you debug your code, not getting someone else to write all the code for you.

Broadly, you're going to be storing the output of the shell script in a variable, and then making an INSERT query to your MySQL database.

Comment: Please read a tutorial about PHP/MySQL.

Comment: Have you tried something? Please paste your code it maybe helps us to suggest a solution to you. ;)

Comment: <?php

echo exec('whoami');
?> . How can I store the output of this command to MYSQL database table?

Answer (score 0):

Try  :

```
exec('whoami >> out.txt');
```

Then you can open the file out.txt and process the output